# keras: how to predict classes in order?

Tags: keras

I'm trying to predict image classes in keras (binary classification). The model accuracy is fine, but it seems that `ImageDataGenerator` shuffles the input images, so I was not able to match the predicted class with the original images.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        pred_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False,
        save_to_dir='images/aug'.format(feature))

print  model.predict_generator(generator, nb_input)
```

For example, if I have `a1.jpg`, `a2.jpg`,..., `a9.jpg` under `pred_data_dir`, I expect to get an array like

```
[class for a1.jpg, class for a2.jpg, ... class for a9.jpg]
```

from `model.predict_generator()`, but actually I got something like

```
[class for a3.jpg, class for a8.jpg, ... class for a2.jpg]
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to predict on those images, use your validation/test set directly.

Comment: The goal here is not to get the accuracy score, but to predict labels for new dataset.

Comment: Yes, then the question makes no sense, you don't need the training set labels for that.

Comment: In any case, predict on your raw images, not on the augmented ones.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro What's the construct to predict_generator the raw image? I had the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475048/how-to-get-the-class-label-from-predict-generator-in-r-keras

Comment: What is nb_input here. I just get a list of probabilites. Can't figure out which classes they belong to.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the source code of `flow_from_directory`. In my case, I had to rename all images. They were named 1.jpg .. 1000.jpg, but to be in order, they had to be named 0001.jpg .. 1000.jpg. The sorting is important here.

`flow_from_directory` uses `sorted(os.listdir(directory))`, thus the sorting is not always intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The `flow_from_directory()` method returns a `DirectoryIterator` object with a `filenames` member that lists all the files. Since that member is used for subsequent batch generation and iteration, you should be able to use it to match your filenames to predictions.

For your example, `generator.filenames` should give you a parallel list like `['a3.jpg', 'a8.jpg', ..., 'a2.jpg']`.